# How to convert LVM mirror to linear after disk failure

Tags: linux, lvm, mirroring

I have an ubuntu system with a simple mirrored LV in LVM. One of my disks has failed, and thus I removed it. However, i cannot seem to reduce my LV to linear.

I suspect my problem arose when I first reduced the VG, before un-mirroring the LV.

My setup is quite simple, I have one vg: vg-tank:

```
vgs
  VG      #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  vg-tank   1   1   0 wz--n- <3,64t <1,04t
```

On it, is one mirrored disk zeus:

```
lvs --all --segments -o +devices
  LV              VG      Attr       #Str Type   SSize Devices                          
  zeus            vg-tank rwi---r---    2 raid1  2,60t zeus_rimage_0(0),zeus_rimage_1(0)
  [zeus_rimage_0] vg-tank Iwi---r---    1 linear 2,60t /dev/sdc1(0)                    
  [zeus_rimage_1] vg-tank vwi---r---    0 error  2,60t                                  
  [zeus_rmeta_0]  vg-tank ewi---r---    1 linear 4,00m /dev/sdc1(681575)                
  [zeus_rmeta_1]  vg-tank ewi---r---    0 error  4,00m
```

One would expect i could just

```
lvconvert -m0 vg-tank/zeus
```

But it will fail on:

```
lvconvert -m0 vg-tank/zeus
  vg-tank/zeus must be active to perform this operation.
```

Lvdisplay indeed tells that it is not active:

```
lvdisplay -v
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg-tank/zeus
  LV Name                zeus
  VG Name                vg-tank
  LV UUID                cVhQI9-9fPC-V3sq-doap-30BX-IU74-Bwxg5K
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time kiezeltje, 2022-01-08 16:14:24 +0100
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                2,60 TiB
  Current LE             681575
  Mirrored volumes       2
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
```

I have tried activating it, but it will fail on the missing disk:

```
vgchange -v -ay vg-tank --activation-mode degraded
  Activating logical volume vg-tank/zeus.
  activation/volume_list configuration setting not defined: Checking only host tags for vg-tank/zeus.
  Creating vg--tank-zeus_rmeta_0
  Loading table for vg--tank-zeus_rmeta_0 (253:0).
  Resuming vg--tank-zeus_rmeta_0 (253:0).
  Creating vg--tank-zeus_rimage_0
  Loading table for vg--tank-zeus_rimage_0 (253:1).
  Resuming vg--tank-zeus_rimage_0 (253:1).
  Creating vg--tank-zeus_rmeta_1
  Loading table for vg--tank-zeus_rmeta_1 (253:2).
  Resuming vg--tank-zeus_rmeta_1 (253:2).
  Creating vg--tank-zeus_rimage_1
  Loading table for vg--tank-zeus_rimage_1 (253:3).
  Resuming vg--tank-zeus_rimage_1 (253:3).
  Creating vg--tank-zeus
  Loading table for vg--tank-zeus (253:4).
  device-mapper: reload ioctl on  (253:4) failed: Invalid argument
  Removing vg--tank-zeus (253:4)
  Removing vg--tank-zeus_rimage_1 (253:3)
  Removing vg--tank-zeus_rmeta_1 (253:2)
  Removing vg--tank-zeus_rimage_0 (253:1)
  Removing vg--tank-zeus_rmeta_0 (253:0)
  Activated 0 logical volumes in volume group vg-tank.
  0 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg-tank" now active
```

I have searched a lot, but cannot seem to find how to remedy this situation.
The best would be to convert the LV to a linear one, and then insert a new disk.